# .wrap() jQuery-Created Button in jQuery-Created <div>

Tags: comments, jquery

I am currently using the following script to create a button to show/hide comments on WordPress.  However, I would like to wrap the `<button>` the code generates in a `<div>`, but I cannot seem to get that portion of the code working properly.  Here's the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

// Get #comment-section div
var commentsDiv = jQuery('#comment-section');

// Only do this work if that div isn't empty
if (commentsDiv.length) {

// Hide #comment-section div by default
jQuery(commentsDiv).hide();

// Append a link to show/hide
jQuery('<button/>')
    .attr('class', 'toggle-comments')
    .attr('href', '#')
    .html('Show Comments <span class="icon_comment"></span>')
    .insertBefore(commentsDiv);

// Encase button in #toggle-comments-container div
jQuery('<div/>')
    .attr('id', 'toggle-comments-container')
    .wrap('.toggle-comments');

// When show/hide is clicked
jQuery('.toggle-comments').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

// Show/hide the div using jQuery's toggle()
jQuery(commentsDiv).toggle('slow', function() {
// change the text of the anchor
    var anchor = jQuery('.toggle-comments');
    var anchorText = anchor.html() == 'Show Comments <span class="icon_comment"></span>' ? 'Hide Comments <span class="icon_comment"></span>' : 'Show Comments <span class="icon_comment"></span>';
    jQuery(anchor).html(anchorText);
});
});

} // End of commentsDiv.length

});
```

The code generates the button as expected, but does not wrap it in the `<div>` as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got the [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function wrong

```
jQuery('.toggle-comments').wrap(jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'toggle-comments-container'
}))
```

You need to call the `wrap()` function on the elements which has to be wrapped(in this case `toggle-comments`), then pass the element which has to wrap the elements as the argument(in this case the `div`)